# With an Object create another Object with additional properties, php

Tags: php, oop

**This is my php code:**

```
<?php
tree($Comments, 0, 0);
$var = -1;
function tree($Comments, $parent_id = 0, $level=0, $c=0) {
  global $var;
  foreach($Comments as $Comment) {
      if($Comment['parent_id'] == $parent_id) {
        //create a next instance of the new object with values of this current instance of the old object, like $NewObjectInstance['parent_id']=$Comment['parent_id'] and so on, in this way the new object will be ordered as i want
        If ($level > $var)  $var++; else {  
                for ($i = $var-$level+1; $i>0; $i--) { if ($c < 0) // the value of the new fancy property of new object instance(let's say $NewObjectInstance->design_level) will be incremented by each interation if (if) doesn't work it will be 0
                  else $c--;  };   
                $var=$level; 
                   }; 
        tree($Comments, $Comment['id'], $level+1,$c);
        }
  };
};
?>
```

**I have the $Comments object which contains the values of Table(properties-values):**

```
id
parent_id
id_theme
user
text
upVotes
downVotes
```

My idea is to create with the recursion function above with the help of an object, another object ordered by my own with same properties and values and also with a special property added (design_level). But I am newbie in objects and I am stuck, because I am stuck only with procedural programming, any idea how to make this?

Comment: Your code could need a better indentation. What are you trying to do? Trying to create a new object, but why?

Comment: Domain logic doesnt need to follow the db structure.

Comment: I am creating a new object because I need it ordered in order to create a foreach display of a tree of comments, I really need that new object, really...

Comment: @frz3993 it doesn't need, I mentioned the db in order to mention its properties:id, parent_id, id_theme ...to be easier to undertand